numpy add array of constants to array of matrixes
Consider a numpy array X with m elements. Each element it's itself a numpy matrix of a generic (but, more importantly, fixed shape (n0, n1, ..., n) so that X shape is (m, n0, n1, ..., n).
Now, take a list of m (different) scalar, let's say something like this:
c = np.arange(m)

c and X have the same number of elements: c is an array of m scalar, while X it's an array of m matrixes.
I would like to add to every elements of X[i] the constant c[i]
for i in range(m):
    X[i] += c[i]

is it possible to perform this calculation without the for loop? Something like X+c (but ofc it does not work)
Thank you for your help
EDIT:
Code example
import numpy as np

m = 3
X = np.arange(m*4*3*6*5*7).reshape((m, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7))
c = np.arange(m)
for i in range(m):
    X[i] += c[i]


could you provide a [mre] of X with say 4 items to make your question more explicit? However, if you have an array of arrays (ie. an object dtype), then nothing will be more efficient than a loop

Yes, I added the working code. It requires numpy in order to run

Thank you, so it's not an object array but a NDarray, so yes you can, see below ;)

they have the same first dimension, yes, but not the same number of elements.

@hpaulj X contains m(=3 in the example) matrixes, c contains m(=3 in the example) scalar. I don't know what you mean ^^

X has m*4*3*6*5*7 scalars.

@hpaulj yes, that's correct!

The key to all suggestios is to understand broadcasting.  Some how the (m,...) and (m,) shapes must be adjusted to broadcast.  (m,) adjusts automatically to (1,1,1,m), but to get (m,1,1,1) you have to be explicit.  Or change X to be (....,m).

For this I assume that each element m is the same size, for example:
X = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],[2, 3, 4, 5]])
m = X.shape[0]
c = np.arange(m) + 1 # np.array([1, 2])

Now you can use a transpose of X
(X.T + c).T
array([[2, 3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])

And for your code it also works, for example:
X = np.arange(m*4*3*6*5*7).reshape((m, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7))
X[2,0,0,0,0,0]
>>> array([5040, 5041, 5042, 5043, 5044, 5045, 5046])
X = (X.T + c).T
X[2,0,0,0,0,0]
>>> array([5042, 5043, 5044, 5045, 5046, 5047, 5048])


X[2,0,0,0,0,0] is more idiomatic in numpy

import numpy as np

m = 3
n0, n1, n2 = 2, 3, 4  


X = np.arange(m * n0 * n1 * n2).reshape((m, n0, n1, n2))
c = np.arange(m)  # Scalars to be added

c_expanded = c[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
X_updated = X + c_expanded


You can use:
X += c[:,None,None,None,None,None]

Or:
X += c.reshape(c.shape+(1,)*(X.ndim-1))

Checking that is produces the same as the loop:
np.allclose(X, X_loop)
# True


@MrFooz no that wouldn't work, since c is one-dimensional c[:, ...] is the same as c ;)

Looks like X.T[:] += c will also work.  So either we adjust c so it broadcasts to the shape of X, or make a view of X that works with c.

@hpaulj yes, using a view is a good suggestion :)
